# Animation starting from the front of the screen

Tags: android, animation

I am a newbie in android. I need to complete a task which deals with the animation of the dynamic dashboards moving into the layout from the front of the screen as in for example in the link http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html as the icons get into the screen from the front of the `view in 0.05 seconds`. I used different types of animations. I feel that transition animation has to yield the solution. But am not able to come up with any solution.

Please help me and show me a way to move in the imageViews into the layout.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on "Zoom in" or "Modern zoom in" animation. You can find an example in ApiDemos project: App/Activity/Animation.